# JQuery-ui Dialog: How can I prevent default action when the user clicks on close button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i'm using JQuery-ui dialog;

i'd like to perform my custom actions when user clicks on dialog's close button [X], but i'd like to prevent the closing event too!

i tried this code without success:

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
       close: function(event, ui) {
          event.preventDefault();
          //mycode              
          }
});
```

Even if i wrote the code above the dialog is closed bypassing my "preventDefault".

Thank you!

MV

Comment: maybe return false; ? :)
Or just hide [x] button and add your own cancel button

Answer (score 5):

I've been looking for an answer to this too - so far the best I've come up with is

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   beforeClose: function(event, ui) {
      //mycode              
      return false;
      }
});
```

Comment: Have you looked at the other answer to this question? there is a `beforeclosingevent` which you can use.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.selector').bind('dialogbeforeclose', function(event,ui){
  alert('hello');
});
```